# Add a Page to a Spring Boot App (Extremely Basic)

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring boot api. My problem is how do I actually create a page in my app?

I created a page in /resources/static/templates/index.html

and when I get to `/api/lol` I just see a string saying index and not the page.

How do I do this?

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/lol")
    String lol() {            
          return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Intellij IDEA if that helps

Answer (score 3):

You annotated your class with `@RestController`.
What you want is a MVC Controller, so replace it with `@Controller`.

Here is an example of the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-controller) :

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String handle(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: where do I put the html? I get Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: You could try : `src/main/resources/templates/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Put your index.html in `src/main/resources/static`

and then in your controller

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/lol")
    String lol() {            
          return "index.html";
    }
}
```